# Is there any C++ reference manual as C:a reference manual?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any books which covers the latest standard of c++ ,I want to know much about this standards to use.I want to read a book like the book --> C a reference manual by sir Harbison .

Comment: the user asked a normal question. why are you voting it down????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stroustrup is publishing 4th edition of C++ Programming Language in early 2013. You can preorder it now on amazon. Along with all other stuff, it will include a comprehensive reference to C++ 11 features.

Edit: Here's [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840)